# VS2012 and VS2013 installed msbuild failing on automated test

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

I installed VS2012 on my workstation. I am using TFS 2012 for build server. Several months later, I installed VS2013 and worked in that for a while.

Now I'm back to working with a solution in VS2012 and added a unit test project. I queued my build and I get errors.

First error I got was:

> TF900547: The directory containing the assemblies for the Visual
>   Studio Test Runner is not valid ''.

So I researched that and someone suggested changing 
Build Definition > Process > Automated Tests > to use MSTest.

Well, when I did that I got the following error:

> File not found: MSTest.exe

What might be going on here, and how I can troubleshoot this?

### Update

I installed vs2012 on a clean Windows 7 virtual machine.

Created a simple unit test project (checked into TFS) and a simple build in TFS and still got the following error:

> TF900547: The directory containing the assemblies for the Visual
>   Studio Test Runner is not valid

Maybe this is why? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399135%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#test

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. My build server version was TFS 2015. The projects use Visual Studio 2013 and that was installed to build server also. (In other build server that was version TFS 2013 it worked).

I needed to install also Visual Studio 2015 to the build server. After that mstest.exe was found By the test. My theory is that the Visual Studio version that corresponds to the build server TFS version must be installed to the build server.